# Rattling/buzzing from engine bay before start

Tags: engine

if I turn the key before starting the car, a quite loud buzzing can be heard from under the hood. The car can be started and runs fine for over more than half a year, is this normal?

I’ve made a video with the sound: https://youtube.com/shorts/vMjGoICo_DY?feature=share

Hopefully you can help :)

Comment: It does not sound like a relay, more like say the fuel pump. On my car, I occasionally hear the fuel pump make a brief noise before engaging the starter motor.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I hear this sound every time I put the key on contact before ignition. Maybe it’s the fuel pump indeed but not sure if the sound is normal.

Comment: It does not sound normal.

Comment: The noise you're hearing I believe is from the EGR vacuum solenoid. This is what actuates the EGR while the engine is running, acting as a valve for the vacuum control of the EGR itself. It should not be cycling all the time especially before startup. Have you looked to see if there are any codes present? Also, could you please put the year/make/model/engine of the car into the question by editing it?

Comment: I’ve disconnected the powercord nearby the sound and afterwards it was completely gone. Took a picture of the component  and it turns out to be the boost valve. Ordered a new one. Thanks for your answers!